# How to style same class name value with different color

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Suppose i have 2 values of same class with "MyTitle". How do i style 2 values to have different color?

```
<div class="MyTitle">Insert text here</div>
<div class="MyTitle">Insert text here</div>
```

I want the 1st value of Insert text here to have red, followed by green?

I did this way, but it applies to both, any idea how to tackle this issue?

```
.MyTitle {
 color: red;
}
```

Comment: Just a comment - it's common practice to use id's for hear situations rather than `nth-child` but if you don't have access to the html then `nth-child`is the devoid you're looking for.

Comment: Using IDs is bad practice. Add a second class or use nth-child is better.

Comment: Adding a second class is a better option, you you have a pattern use nth-class instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the :nth-child() selector.

Example below:

```
.MyTitle:nth-child(1) {
//This will style the first element
color: red;
}
.MyTitle:nth-child(2) {
//This will style the second element
color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give the other class `id`

```css
.Mytitle#second {
  color: red;
}

.Mytitle#first {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="first" class="Mytitle"> text </div>
<div id="second" class="Mytitle"> text </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It works if you add differents id's in your div's. For example:

```
.MyTitle#first {
color: red; 
}
.MyTitle#second {
color: green; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use one more class.

```css
.MyTitle {
  color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyTitle">Insert Text 1</div>
<div class="MyTitle green">Insert Text 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `nth-child(n)` selector

```css
.MyTitle:nth-child(1) {
 color: red;
}

.MyTitle:nth-child(2) {
 color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyTitle">Insert text here</div>
<div class="MyTitle">Insert text here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ***:nth-of-type***, Using **:nth-child** is not safe. You can use **:nth-of-type** instead. 
Ex:

```
<section>
  <h1>Words</h1>
  <p>Little</p>
  <p>Piggy</p>    <!-- Want this one -->
</section>


p:nth-child(2) { color: red; } /* Now incorrect */

p:nth-of-type(2) { color: red; } /* Still works */
```

See below-given link for more details.
[the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/)

Answer (score -2):

Try to style it within HTML so it will be used once for this one element you want to have the diffrent color like :

```css
.MyTitle{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="MyTitle">Insert text here.</div>
<div class="MyTitle" style="color: green !important;">Insert text here.</div>
<div class="MyTitle">Insert text here.</div>
```